# Customizing cover sheet for dissertation

Tags: titles, templates

Hi I am working on my dissertation. I need my cover sheet to be like following.

```
                     Dissertation Title

                         My name
                         (centered)

                  A dissertation submitted 
                     to University....
                      (centered)

                  Copyrights This copy of 
                  Dissertation supplied...
```

But I don't know how to do it exactly. Can anyone please help me with it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code, you can start with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}% empty header/footer

\begin{center}\strut
\bfseries\Huge
Dissertation Title
\end{center}
\vfill

\centerline{My name}
\vfill

\begin{center}\strut
A dissertation submitted \\
to University \ldots\\
So and So
\end{center}
\vfill

\begin{center}\strut
Copyrights This copy of \\
Dissertation supplied...
\end{center}
\clearpage

%If required, add body text from here

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes the main things are ..
- the `center` environment for horizontal spacing..
- the combination of `vfill` (acting as springs) and \clearpage` for vertical spacing...

If you are interested you could use and customize my [package](http://www.ed389.upmc.fr/fr/_docs/pagedecouv.tar.gz)